# STL-like graph implementation

Tags: c++, classes, graph, stl

I have implemented an STL-like graph class. Could someone review it and tell me things that I could add to it?

**File graph.hpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using std::vector;
using std::list;

#ifndef GRAPH_IMPL
#define GRAPH_IMPL

namespace graph {
  struct node
  {
    int v,w;
  };

  template<class T, bool digraph>
  class graph;

  template<class T>
  class vertex_impl
  {
    friend class graph<T,true>;
    friend class graph<T,false>;
  private:
    list<node> adj;
    int index;
    T masking;
  public:
    vertex_impl(int index = -1, const T& masking = T()) : index(index), masking(masking){}
    vertex_impl(const vertex_impl& other) : index(other.index), masking(other.masking){}

    typedef typename list<node>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename list<node>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef typename list<node>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename list<node>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename list<node>::size_type size_type;

    iterator begin() { return adj.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return adj.begin(); }

    iterator end() { return adj.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return adj.end(); }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return adj.rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return adj.begin(); }

    reverse_iterator rend() { return adj.rend(); } 
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return adj.rend(); }

    size_type degree() const { return adj.size(); }

    int name() const { return index; }
    const T& mask() const { return masking; }
    void set_mask(const T& msk) { masking = msk; }
  };

  template<class T, bool digraph>
  class graph
  {
  private:
    vector<vertex_impl<T> > adj;
    typename vector<vertex_impl<T> >::size_type V,E;
  public:
    typedef vertex_impl<T> vertex;
    typedef typename vector<vertex>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename vector<vertex>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef typename vector<vertex>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename vector<vertex>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename vector<vertex>::size_type size_type;

    graph(size_type v) : adj(v), V(v), E(0)
    {
      for(size_type i = 0; i < v; ++i) {
        adj[i].index = i;
      }
    }

    iterator begin() { return adj.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return adj.begin(); }

    iterator end() { return adj.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return adj.end(); }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return adj.rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return adj.rbegin(); }

    reverse_iterator rend() { return adj.rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return adj.rend(); }

    void insert(int from, int to, int weight = 1)
    {
      adj[from].adj.push_back((node){to,weight});
      E++;
      if(!digraph)
      adj[to].adj.push_back((node){from,weight});
    }

    void erase(int from, int to)
    {
      for(typename vertex::iterator i = adj[from].begin(); i != adj[from].end();) {
        if(i->v == to) {
          i = adj[from].adj.erase(i);
          E--;
        } else {
          ++i;
        }
      }
      if(!digraph) {
        for(typename vertex::iterator i = adj[to].begin(); i != adj[to].end();) {
          if(i->v == from) {
            i = adj[to].adj.erase(i);
          } else {
            ++i;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    size_type vertices() const { return V; }
    size_type edges() const { return E; }

    vertex& operator[](int i) { return adj[i]; }
    const vertex& operator[](int i) const { return adj[i]; }
  };
}
#endif
```

**File main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "graph.hpp"

int main()
{
  graph::graph<char*,false> gr(5);
  int m;

  scanf("%d", &m);

  for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    gr.insert(a,b);
  }

  for(graph::graph<char*,false>::size_type i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("%d: ", gr[i].name());
    for(graph::graph<char*,false>::vertex::iterator j = gr[i].begin(); j != gr[i].end(); ++j) {
      printf(" %d", j->v);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my blog post where it says how can we create a C++ graph using STL:
http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2014/02/creating-graph-using-stls-in-c.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- your `node` type doesn't seem to be a node, but an *edge* (or an adjacency relationship, or something). Unless this implementation is based on some literature which describes entries in the adjacency list as *nodes*, I'd consider renaming it
- I have no idea what *mask* and *masking* are supposed to mean. They may be meaningful names in the context where you're using this graph, but it isn't clear that they are in a generic graph. It's just where the user attaches their arbitrary data to each vertex, right? Is it even used?
- the number of vertices is fixed at creation time, and you can only add edges. Is that sensible?
- `graph::insert` doesn't check whether `from` and `to` are valid indices
- what does `digraph` mean here - directed graph? Because there is [another meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) which is totally unrelated. Why not just say "directed"?
- it looks like `graph::V` is *always* identical to `adj.size()` (and is anyway never used), so you can remove it
- `vertex_impl` is an internal implementation detail, yet you're exposing it. STL containers hide these details (list & tree nodes for example) inside the iterator, and only expose the user data. Is there a useful way of iterating *transparently* over the graph without exposing this?

Answer (score 5):

The point of the include guards is to prevent multiple inclusion of anything.
So always put them at the top of the file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#ifndef GRAPH_IMPL
#define GRAPH_IMPL
```

Because these are not at the top you include vector/list every time. This is just more work that does not need to be done.

Never put using statements in a header file (in global context).

```
using std::vector;
using std::list;
```

Anybody that uses your header file now implicitly pulls vector/list into the global namespace. This can have undesirable effects with name resolution. Don't do this in a header file. If you must be lazy then use scope so you are not forcing your requirements onto others. There is always a typedef to make things easier.

Comments (or well named members) would be an idea.

```
  struct node
  {
    int v,w;
  };
```

No idea what that will be used for.
If the user of your code library should not be seeing this then it should also be contained inside the private part of a classs so that they don't accidentally use it.

#### vertex_impl

- Not sure what `vertex_impl` is for?
- Is it exposed externally?
- What is it implementing (its name contains `impl`)?
- Why can it have more than two nodes (To me a vertex is an edge that connects two nodes)?
- Why does the constructor not fully initialize the object (index is set externally).
- What is `masking` for?
- What is `index` for?

When I build objects that contain containers I abstract the container used:

```
list<node> adj;
```

Here I would have gone:

```
typedef std::list<node>  Container;
Container  adj;
```

Then I would derive the other iterator types from Container. This means if the code changes there is only one location where the code needs to change.

Having an explicit `rbegin()` and `rend()` implies that there is some ordering to the nodes. personally I would leave them out as their does not seem to be any way to logically define the order of traversal of a graph. If the user wants to iterate in the reverse order then can use `std::reverse_iterator`.

#### graph

Basically the same comments as vertex_impl